# Is there any other way to optimize this function or better approach?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote a function using react and it works properly and as expected, My only problem is if there are any other way to optimize it just for readability and better approach

Here is my code:

```
export const formatter = (num, lastDigit = 3) => {
  if (num.length === 13) {
    return `xxxx xxxx xx ${num.substr(num.length - lastDigit)}`;
  } else if (num.length === 14) {
    return `xxxx xxxx xxx ${num.substr(num.length - lastDigit)}`;
  } else {
    return `xxxx xxxx xxxx ${num.substr(num.length - lastDigit)}`;
  }
};
```

Comment: What are you optimising for? Performance? Readability? Conciseness? Anything else?

Comment: For readability

Comment: You could reduce duplication by storing the result of `${num.substr(num.length - lastDigit)}` in a variable and then concatenate it with the other string that contains 'x''s.

Comment: Give some test cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For readability:

- Move repetitive code to a constant
- Using `switch` instead of `if`/`else` is simpler to read because it is easier to see that the logic is dealing with different options for a single value

```js
export const formatter = (num, lastDigit = 3) => {
  const value = num.substr(num.length - lastDigit);

  switch(num.length) {
    case 13:
      return `xxxx xxxx xx ${value}`;
    case 14:
      return `xxxx xxxx xxx ${value}`;
    default:
      return `xxxx xxxx xxxx ${value}`;
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For better Readability you may try this:

```
export const formatter = (num, lastDigit = 3) => {
  const length = num.length;
  const subString = num.substr(num.length - lastDigit);
   
  if (length === 13) {
    return `xxxx xxxx xx ${subString}`;
  } else if (num.length === 14) {
    return `xxxx xxxx xxx ${subString}`;
  } else {
    return `xxxx xxxx xxxx ${subString}`;
  }
};
```